# pandas apply to append total row

Tags: python, pandas

I have gone through numerous examples of putting a Total row to the end of a dataframe. I am just curious to know that why can't below approach work:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {
    'a' : [1,2 ,3, 4, 5],
    'b' : [3, 5, 7, 9, 10]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
# print(df)

def func(x):
    x['sum'] = x.sum()

df2 = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=0)

print(df2)
```

In this, x is always a Series containing a full column and I am appending an index called sum. Please guide.

EDIT: If we can calculate sum with axis=1 why can't we do it with axis=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here missing `return x` from your function:

```
def func(x):
    x['sum'] = x.sum()
    return x

df2 = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=0)
print(df2)

      a   b
0     1   3
1     2   5
2     3   7
3     4   9
4     5  10
sum  15  34
```

But simpliest is use [`setting with enlargement`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc['sum'] = df.sum()
```

Comment: thank a ton! I am new to python, still have lots to learn.. :)